# Will a Feb 2nd transit in Shanghai prevent US entry in April?

Tags: usa, air-travel, china, event-based-effects, covid-19

I am a Canadian passport holder,would I be allowed to enter US since my passport has China stamp from Feb 2, 2020. I had a flight that transited in Shanghai. And this April 2020 I have travel plan to US.

Comment: Not sure it’s feasible to comment on what restrictions might be the case in April.

Comment: Assuming the travel restriction does not become stricter, you can enter the US if you have not been in China within 14 days of your entry into US. IMO, I don't think it's likely that you'll have a problem with this in April, assuming you do not travel to China or other epidemic country in the meantime, the virus isn't a supervirus that has much longer incubation period and your current residence country will not become an epidemic area.

Comment: @zhantongz "and your current residence country will not become an epidemic area": you never know. It totally could...

Answer (score 2):

The current [rules](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/from-china.html) that apply to you are:

> Foreign nationals who have visited China in the past 14 days may not enter the United States.

You could enter the US today, since it has been more than 14 days since your transit.

A lot could happen between now and April:

- cases could start to spread within Canada. Unlikely at the moment; [our cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_outbreak_by_country_and_territory#Canada) are essentially all recovered except for someone in BC who caught it in Iran; in country transmission has been very small and easily traceable (eg a family member of a known case.)
- new information about the transmission could lead to lengthening 14 days to 60 or 90 days. Even more unlikely. I could see 21 but not more than that. You will be over 60 days by the time you want to travel.
- the borders could just entirely close. Really really unlikely.

As far as these sorts of predictions can be made, I don't expect your April plans to be affected by what you did in February or where you currently live.

Comment: Thank you all for these helpful informations